# Regular expression between curly braces, but ignore nested

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that find strings between curly braces, but ignores nested (if there are). For example, the next string:

> reset survey 888 ${d14322a2-bc13-4fcb-9da3-{sdfdsf}e2346a7d58ec} for
>   the participant ${c45e9bc0-6043-4aa1-8de0-27f8f8aade82}

Should only match the next two:

1. d14322a2-bc13-4fcb-9da3-{sdfdsf}e2346a7d58ec
2. c45e9bc0-6043-4aa1-8de0-27f8f8aade82

Based on the answers, I'm going to add another example:

> {@aaa Location}
>   {@eee header}
>   {@bbb {http://www.uytuty.org/879/fghdhgfd}hgjdg}
>   {@gfh fdgdf gd dfgfdg.}

It should match:

1. @aaa Location
2. @eee header
3. @bbb {http://www.uytuty.org/879/fghdhgfd}hgjdg
4. @gfh fdgdf gd dfgfdg.

Comment: What about `blah blah{foo} blah {bar} blah`?

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: @Toto that should only display:
foo bar

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: @Toto I'm getting one error when I try it in Java. In the web example it looks good.

Comment: I don't know how regex is working in Java. May be recursive regex is not understanding. Could you give the error you got? And real test case and code you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for recursion.

If your regex flavour supports it, you can use:

```
(?<={)([^{}]++|\{(?1)\})+(?=})
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/87NgeI/1)

Answer (score 0):

`(?!\{)[\w\-\{\}]+(?=\})`

Let's break it down:

- `(?!abc)` - negative look ahead. The matching string is excluded from
  the result.
- `(?=abc)` - positive look ahead. The matching string is
  excluded from the result.
- `[\w\-\{\}]+` - any alphanumeric character
  (including underscore) and curly braces.

Tested on https://regexr.com/4q128

Comment: You are close to it, but it didn't work with the second example I have added.

Comment: in lamens terms what is the difference between negative and positive lookaheads?

Comment: @CyberStems: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html